# Sql query for comparing rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Let's suppose we have a table:

```
id1  id2
1    2
2    1
3    4
4    3
```

The expected output is

```
id1  id2
1    2 
3    4
```

Rows 1,2 and 2,1 are same, and only one needs to be outputted.
What's the SQL query for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `RDBMS` supports `LEAST` and `GREATEST` (Oracle does):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT LEAST(id1, id2), GREATEST(id1, id2)
FROM    mytable
```

Cross-platform version:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END,
        CASE WHEN id1 > id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ...
From MyTable As T
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From MyTable As T2
                Where T2.id1 = T.id2
                    And T2.id2 = T.id1
                )
    And T.id1 < T.id2
```

Another solution using Union

```
Select T.id1, T.id2
From MyTable As T
Where T.id1 <= T.id2
Union 
Select T.id2, T.id1
From MyTable As T
Where T.id1 > T.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what you're trying to do is: return rows were id1 matches id2 and id2 matches id1, but only return rows from that set when id1 is also less than or equal to id2.

`select x.id1, x.id2 from
myTable x, myTable y
where x.id1 = y.id2 and y.id1 = x.id2 and x.id1 <= y.id1`

Answer (score 0):

Exact same question I also had to solve recently. See [Eliminating duplicates](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2011/03/03/eliminating-duplicates/).

```
select id1, id2
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t
  where id1 = t.id2
  and id2 = t.id1
  and rowid > t.rowid
);
```